# 1 Network with 2 Gateways

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, routing

I have a network which is connected to the internet. The range and subnet is 192.168.1.0/24.

I also have an AP that is a Point-to-Point network which has the range and subnet of 172.18.53.12/30

I would like to set this up (without using static IPs on the user computers) so that a user can access both networks simultaneously.

Any advice?

Regards,

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser Robert. Can you please tell us what Operating System you are using so that people can give specific help.

Comment: I'd like to do it with a router, the one i have is a Billion. If i need to use a firewall for the dual gateways, then I will have to set up PF Sense or something. Preferable if i can do it with out a firewall that will be great

Comment: How is this Access Point of yours connected to the router/the "regular" network? Who's on the other side of the PtP link? Is it something you want to access?

Comment: I can plug the AP straight into one of the LAN ports, or I can get a 2nd router and plug it into that - whatever will work.
Yes I want to access the other side of the PTP.

Comment: Hm, I think I sort-of get it, but could please make a graph showing devices, connections between them and subnets on connections and from where to where the new route should provide access?